# Same exact docker image, services within running container have two different behaviors

Tags: docker

My `entrypoint.sh` file looks like this:

```
root@e7ebb78ed443:/# cat /opt/entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /
systemctl start mosquitto.service
systemctl start notus-scanner
systemctl start postgresql@14-main
systemctl start redis-server@openvas.service
systemctl start ospd-openvas
systemctl start gvmd
systemctl start gsad
exec "$@"
```

It only works if I manually start the `gvmd` service using `systemctl start gvmd`, on top of what already ran when executing the entrypoint.sh file.

However, I notice on one system, the `gvmd` service starts just fine, whereas on the next system, the `gvmd` service doesn't start because it has a fatal issue with PostgreSQL.

When inspecting the log files of `gvmd` on the second system, I'm seeing:

```
md   main:MESSAGE:2023-01-12 21h05.46 utc:46:    Greenbone Vulnerability Manager version 22.4.0~dev1 (DB revision 250)
md manage:WARNING:2023-01-12 21h05.46 utc:47: sql_open: PQconnectPoll failed
md manage:WARNING:2023-01-12 21h05.46 utc:47: sql_open: PQerrorMessage (conn): connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
md manage:WARNING:2023-01-12 21h05.46 utc:47: init_manage_open_db: sql_open failed
```

However, the first system shows me this:

```
md   main:MESSAGE:2023-01-12 18h06.42 utc:52:    Greenbone Vulnerability Manager version 22.4.0~dev1 (DB revision 250)
md manage:   INFO:2023-01-12 18h06.46 UTC:72: osp_scanner_feed_version: No feed version available yet. OSPd OpenVAS is still starting
md manage:   INFO:2023-01-12 18h06.56 UTC:80: osp_scanner_feed_version: No feed version available yet. OSPd OpenVAS is still starting
md manage:   INFO:2023-01-12 18h07.06 UTC:84: osp_scanner_feed_version: No feed version available yet. OSPd OpenVAS is still starting
```

and the service runs just fine.

The interesting thing here is that both systems are running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and Docker version 20.10.21. The images are exactly the same and the host OS are the same, with the same services/ports exposed.

I'm running docker in the following manner on both systems:

```
docker run --privileged --rm --name openvas -ti <my_image> /bin/bash
```

The sha256 of the image is exactly the same on both systems, so I'm not even sure where to begin troubleshooting. Considering the purpose of docker is to have a consistent image across multiple platforms, I'm a bit torn on how to begin troubleshooting/resolving this.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I occasionally run into production bugs with my docker env that is the same in staging and development. It normally comes down to ports not being exposed correctly, file mapping errors, communication between containers, or even variances in the host system. You note `They're almost exact clones.`, what are the differences for clarity?

Comment: what happens if you swap the images to the opposite hosts? same thing? sounds like a host issue, rather than an image issue.  maybe check the host logs? are they similar or same hardware? different network cards? maybe a driver is out of date on the "bad" host? do you get different results if you start the "bad" one first? ( swap startup order )

Comment: Thanks @ViaTech I clarified -- the images are the same and the host OS is the same. Both just have docker installed. The other interesting though is that I'm not exposing any ports from the container or host to the container. Really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the relevant error message is

> md manage:WARNING:2023-01-12 21h05.46 utc:47: sql_open: PQerrorMessage (conn): connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  **the database system is starting up**

I.e., `gvmd` can not connect to PostgreSQL because the database is still starting up and not ready for connections, yet.

This also gives a simple explanation why this can be working on one host but not on another host with the exact same image etc.: it is a race condition!

It may be that on the first system PostgreSQL is starting up faster - due to a fewer data in the database which is faster to initialize or due to a faster harddrive - and thus is ready as soon as `gvmd` tries to connect.
Or the other way around: `gvmd` is starting up slower giving PostgreSQL more time to initialize...

A quick - and quite dirty! - solution could be to just additional waiting time in your entrypoint script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd /
systemctl start mosquitto.service
systemctl start notus-scanner
systemctl start postgresql@14-main
systemctl start redis-server@openvas.service
systemctl start ospd-openvas

# wait 10s to allow databases to be ready
sleep 10

systemctl start gvmd
systemctl start gsad
exec "$@"
```

A better way, though, would be to wait/detect when the database is ready to accept connections. Even better this would be done by adjusted `systemd` unit files automatically for you, such that `systemctl start gvmd` will wait until the database is available.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I did try a `sleep 10` after each `systemctl` command but without any luck; however, I will definitely try it again and accept as answer if this works. I also tried adding `After=postgresql@14-main` in the .service file of gvmd but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Adding a sleep of 60 seconds to be on the safe side did the trick. Thanks!